# Logging in Talend ESB

Tags: talend

We had a web service developed in Talend and deployed in TAC(Talend runtime). Service is working fine on the local system but not after the deployment.We had tried various methods to debug it like placing the logger component and putting logging mechanism in Java component of Talend but those messages are not populating in the log file.Please suggest.

Comment: Log file of the TAC contains the output thant appear in console if the job runned in the studio, so make sure that logging component write to the console.

Comment: I put the logger and syso(Sytem.out.prinln()) in my Talend job and seeing the messages in console also. But after deploying it on TAC, not seeing those log messages and syso in the Log file.

Answer (score 0):

Talend Enterprise 5.6 comes with log4j logging. (It can be enabled in the project settings.) Maybe open studio has this feature as well.

If you activate that and start the logserver (based on Kibana / Logstash) you could have a web interface that shows the log messages in real-time, across all the deploys you have.

We're using this approach for development and some production projects. It tells you all the SQL-s connection details, execution times, records fetched, etc..

Answer (score 0):

In TAC you should see the same logs if you click on the magnifier button on the corresponding job on Job Conductor tab. In case if it's empty, check the log4j setting in File->Edit Project Properties->Log4J, and make sure that the default CONSOLE appender is enabled. 
 Also try to build the project manually, and check the log4j.properties in the built zip file.

Finally check the log level at the job properties on TAC->Job Conductor, and make sure it set to the right level.